# deutschsprachige Etiketten (Tags in german language)

Tags: discussion, tags

scroll down for english translation

Die Seite »german.stackexchange.com« behandelt Fragen rund um die deutsche Sprache. Soweit ich das erkennen kann, besteht ihre Aufgabe *NICHT* darin ausschließlich Benutzern, deren Muttersprache Englisch ist, beim Erlernen von Deutsch als Fremdsprache zu helfen.

Die Seite wird nämlich auch von vielen Personen wie mir benutzt, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist, um Feinheiten der deutschen Sprache zu diskutieren.

Und nicht zuletzt gibt es auch Benutzer die Englisch entweder gar nicht oder nur schlecht beherrschen, die aber trotzdem Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen wollen. Franzosen, Italiener, Russen usw. möchten vielleicht auch gerne Deutsch lernen ohne gezwungen zu sein sich mit englischen Begriffen befassen zu müssen.

Daher stelle ich die derzeit angewandte Praxis in Frage, Etiketten (Tags) für Fragen auch dann ausschließlich in englischer Sprache anzugeben, wenn die Frage auf Deutsch gestellt wird, und wenn zu erwarten ist, dass auch alle Antworten und Kommentare auf Deutsch erscheinen werden.

Ich schlage vor, dass bei Fragen, die in Deutsch gestellt werden, auch deutschsprachige Etiketten erlaubt sein sollen.

Noch ein paar Zahlen:
Von den derzeit auf der Erde lebenden ca. 7,2 Milliarden Menschen sprechen nur ca. 340 Millionen Englisch als Muttersprache. Die Schätzungen darüber, wie viele Englisch als Fremdsprache beherrschen bewegen sich zwischen 350 Millionen und 1,1 Milliarden.

Also sprechen maximal 15% aller Menschen englisch. Möglicherweise ist ihr Anteil unter den Besuchern von german.stackexchange.com auch deutlich höher, aber er liegt ganz sicher bei weniger als 100%. Aber 100% aller Besucher von german.stackexchange.com interessieren sich für die deutsche Sprache. Warum also verbietet man deutsche Etiketten und erzwingt englische?

**english translation**

The website "german.stackexchange.com" is about german language. As far as I can see it is NOT only for people who's native language is English and who wants to learn german as a foreign language.

The site is used also by people like me, who's native language is german and who want to discus about details of german language.

And there are people out there, who don't speak english, or whos English is very bad, but who wants to learn german. Maybe French, Italian and Russian people or people from many other countries want to learn german without being forced to deal with tags in english language.

So I think it is no good idea to force people to use tags in english language even if they ask questions in german language, and if you can expect that all comments and answers will be postet in German too.

So I suggest to allow tags in german language when the question is asked in german language.

Some numbers:
There are 7.2 billion people living on earth. Only 340 million of then are native englisch speakers. The estimations on people who speak english as a foreign language go from 350 million to maximum 1.1 billion.

So a maximum of 15 %of all people on earth do understand english tags. Maybe the proportion is much higher among visitors of german.stackexchange.com, but it is definitely less then 100%. But 100 % of all visitors of german.stackexchange.com are interested in german language. So why are people forced to use english tags, and why are german tags prohibited?

Comment: As it is good you brought this discussion up again, may I ask you to contribute on the appropriate Meta question? We should have tags in one language only for better maintenance. Just this one thought for consideration: a long time ago we decided to have English tags. To change this now would be an immense effort (i.e. rename all tags and retag all questions) with probably little value only.

Comment: +1, I do agree that it would be better to have the tags in German. However, I cannot estimate how difficult would be to change them now, but it doesn't seem plausible. I think we just took the wrong decision, since the people who are not able to understand what the German tags mean, won't likely be able to understand German at all. (I actually commented on it in [this question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/609/is-asking-in-english-actually-encouraged-a-criterion)).

Comment: Ah, da schau her! Bin ich nicht mehr alleine. :) Zum Inhalt der Frage: Bezüglich Meta und Tags ist die Diskussion wohl gelaufen. --- Surprise! I'm not longer allone. But for meta and tags, the discussion semms to be over.